# Looping through subdirectories in yeoman and assemble

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, yeoman, assemble, grunt-assemble

I'm very new at Yeoman and Assemble and I'm trying to build a navigation structure with subdirectories.  I can loop through the main pages within the templates/pages directory with this:

```
{{#each pages}}
   <li{{#if this.isCurrentPage}} class="active"{{/if}}>
      <a href="{{relative dest this.dest}}">{{ data.title }}</a>
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

Of course that does not account for subdirectories within the pages directory.  This is what the assemble task of my Gruntfile looks like:

```
assemble: {
  pages: {
    options: {
      flatten: true,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets/',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs',
      plugins: ['assemble-contrib-permalinks'],
    },
    files: {
      '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/**/*.hbs']
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to end up with a nested list that would expose pages within a subdirectory. Is there any somewhat straightforward way of doing this within the loop or do I need to think about hardcoding this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove **`flatten: true`** from option and modify your `pages.files`:

```
files: [
    { expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages', src: ['**/*.hbs'], dest: '<%= config.dist %>' }
]
```

Since you are using permalinks plugin, just add to the end of your `pages.option`:

```
plugins: ['assemble-contrib-permalinks'],
permalinks: {
    preset: 'pretty'
},
```

Now, you navigation should look like this:

```
{{#each pages}}
<li{{#if this.isCurrentPage}} class="active"{{/if}}>
  <a href="{{basename}}/index.html">{{ data.title }}</a>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @user1464317 remember to vote the answer as correct! ;-)

Comment: So I had this issue, but following the above... my dist folder now looks like

./dist/templates/pages/{{basename}}/index.html

I want my dist folder to look like;
./dist/{{basename}}/index.html

as dist is the web root.